# When does an exact functor reflect 0 maps

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products

Let $F$ be an exact functor, for instance $\otimes_k R$ for some algebra $R$ over a field $k$.

Let $V$ be a $k$-vector space.

Let $f_R: V\otimes R \to V\otimes R $ be the 0 map.

Do we have that $f: V \to V$ was $0$ before applying the $\otimes_kR$. It seems natural to me but I can't see why this should be true?

Thank you.

Comment: The question is exceedingly more general than this specific scenario you're asking about. For that, consider that $V\rightarrow V\otimes R,\,v\mapsto v\otimes 1$ is an injection, unless $R=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category, let $\mathcal{B}$ be an additive category, and let $F : \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ be a left- or right-exact functor.
The following are equivalent:

1. $F$ is faithful.
2. $F$ reflects zero morphisms.
3. $F$ reflects zero objects.
4. (Assuming $F$ is exact and $\mathcal{B}$ is abelian.) $F$ reflects isomorphisms.

I leave the proof as an exercise for you.